# How to call a constructor from main method in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a program to solve the eight queens problem and I have no idea how to do it, but I have already started with the multidimensional array. The thing is that I don't know how to call a constructor from the main class, just to check if the array was constructed properly, or how to call it from a method. Can anybody help, please? This is the code, it returns null.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Eightqueens

{
    private static int[][] board;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,board);
    }

    public Eightqueens (int size)
    {
        size = 8;
        board = new int[size][size];

        int row;
        int col;

        for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
            for (col = 0; col < size; col++)
                board[row][col] = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor is only called, if you're instantiating an object from this class. So the question is, where you want to instantiate this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are supposed to use the value passed to the constructor, not overwrite it :

```
...
private int[][] board;
...
public Eightqueens (int size)
{
    size = 8; // remove this
    ...
}

public int[][] getBoard() 
{
    return board;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Eightqueens equeens = new Eightqueens (8); // create an instance
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,equeens.getBoard()); // use accessor to get
                                                            // board
}
```

In addition, it doesn't make sense to initialize a static variable (`board`) in the constructor, since each new instance you create would overwrite its value. I'd change it to non-static, and then you can get it from your instance by using an accessor method (`equeens.getBoard()`).

Answer (score 0):

To call your constructor you must 'construct' a new object.

```
Eightqueens obj = new Eightqueens(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

just when you instantiate your object of class with new keyword , you call your constructor.
like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Eightqueens eq = new Eightqueens(5);
}
```

Comment: That's funny, why did we all chose 5 as a random size parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by calling your constructor by making a new instance of  Eightqueens

```
int size = 1; // anything
new Eightqueens(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does not *return* null, it does not *return* anything. You never call your constructor :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Eightqueens eq = new Eightqueens(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call your constructor again. It only runs at the start of the code.

You can however, create a  new instance of it to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Dialog Box is empty because the value of **board** is **nothing**, which is  because it has not been initialized. The **board** get a value in the constructor method. So you have to call the constructor method before you show the dialog box.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
      Eightqueens eq = new Eightqueens(8);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,board);
}
```

Also, in the constructor method, you are overwriting the value of **size** given by you earlier. Thus, there is practically no need to supply the variable to the method. So, either you remove the line:

```
size = 8;
```

or, change the constructor method to not input the value, like this:

```
public Eightqueens ()
{
    int size = 8;
    board = new int[size][size];
    int row;
    int col;

    for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < size; col++)
              board[row][col] = 0;
}
```